# controlling the width for a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

i was trying to change the width of a particular optional value under `<select>` attribute, something like [this](http://jsbin.com/acado/6). But i am getting troubled as in IE the select box along with the option value gets expanded. Is there any simple way to make the `<option>` only to expand and not the `<select>` box.. mainly in IE ....

Answer (score 5):

```
<select width="123" style="width: 123px;">...</select>
```

Seems to be quite compatible solution working with all newer browsers.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using the jQuery plugin found at
http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/ie-select-style/#demo

The plugin is very simple to use. Here's a breakdown of some full working code.

### HTML

```
<select id="test" >
    <option>choose on</option>
    <option>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
    <option>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
    <option>ccccccccccccccccccccccc</option>
    <option>ddddddddddddddddddddddd</option>
</select>
```

### CSS

```
#test{
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

### jQuery

Don't forget to include the jQuery Js file and this plugins' Js file.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://files.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/ie-select-style/jquery.ie-select-style.min.js"></script>
```

Then put the following right after:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#test').ieSelectStyle();
</script>
```

All this should go before the closing `</body>` tag

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/7Vv8u/2/

Comment: Using javascript and even jQuery to style a native HTML element seems totally wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

Styling `<select>` items is a bit of a problem since there is no cross-browser solution without using JavaScript - since each browser handles rendering of the form controls differently.

I would suggest using an `<ul>` element and applying the functionality/design to act more like a `<select>` element - using JavaScript

**[this](http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/) article may help you with this**